# Permission denied for many directories with Rsync

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, rsync, file-permissions

I'm using Rsync to backup an Ubuntu Server server. I'm getting a lot of permission denied messages. Is there a command I can use to see exactly what directories were denied? I could scroll back up through all the files, but that would take forever. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the rsync again, but drop the -v (so that you only see errors, rather than a complete work log) and add -n (which 'emulates' the rsync, saving you the time of actually transferring the files.)

You could also leave the -v, but use shell redirection to send errors to a different log.  The following should work:

```
rsync -alv -e "ssh -l root" foo:/ /backups/foo/ > r.log 2> r-error.log
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep to search through the warnings / errors - but you'd probably need to run the rsync again to be able to save the output to do this.  (Or save your screen buffer to a file so that you can grep through it.)

What are you backing up?  The entire server?  If so, just make sure you're doing it as `root`, otherwise this will be an expected issue - as there will be at least several files that aren't readable to anyone other than `root`.

Additional details at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync#Rsync_Daemon, including:

> The rsync daemon is an alternative to SSH for remote backups. Although
>   more difficult to configure, it does provide some benefits. For
>   example, using SSH to make a remote backup of an entire system
>   requires that the SSH daemon allow root login, which is considered a
>   security risk. Using the rsync daemon allows for root login via SSH to
>   be disabled.

Comment: The command I used was, sudo rsync -av *******:/ /media/backup1/ubuntubackup. I am backing up an Ubuntu server. I'm guessing not logging in as root is the problem. However, I don't know how to login as root, as I can't issue the sudo command once logged in through Rsync. The backup just starts. I apologize if this is a noob question, but do you have any advice on how to access the Ubuntu server as root through Rsync? If not, I'll post that question by itself.

Comment: @Arthur - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync#Rsync_Daemon.